# I'm getting trouble in using numpy and handling list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

This code read CSV file line by line and counts the number on each Unicode but I can't understand two parts of code like below.I've already googled but I could't find the answer. Could you give me advice ?

1) Why should I use numpy here instead of []?

```
emoji_time = np.zeros(200)
```

2) What does -1 mean ?

````
emoji_time[len(emoji_list)-1] = 1 ```
````

This is the code result:

```
0x100039, 47, 
0x10002D, 121, 
0x100029, 30, 
0x100078, 6,
```

```
unicode_count.py

import codecs
import re
import numpy as np
​
file0 = "./message.tsv"
f0 = codecs.open(file0, "r", "utf-8")
list0 = f0.readlines()
f0.close()
print(len(list0))
​
len_list = len(list0)
emoji_list = []
emoji_time = np.zeros(200)
​
for i in range(len_list):
  a = "0x1000[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]"
  if "0x1000" in list0[i]:   # 0x and 0x1000: same nuumber
    b = re.findall(a, list0[i])
#    print(b)
    for j in range(len(b)):
      if b[j] not in emoji_list:
        emoji_list.append(b[j])
        emoji_time[len(emoji_list)-1] = 1
      else:
        c = emoji_list.index(b[j])
        emoji_time[c] += 1
print(len(emoji_list))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you use a list instead of a numpy array the result should not change in this case. You can try it for yourself running the same code but replacing  `emoji_time = np.zeros(200)` with `emoji_time = [0]*200`.

2)  `emoji_time[len(emoji_list)-1] = 1`. What this line is doing is the follow: If an emoji appears for the first time, 1 is add to `emoji_time`, which is the list that contains the amount of times one emoji occurred. `len(emoji_list)-1` is used to set the position in `emoji_time`, and it is based on the length of `emoji_list` (the minus 1 is only needed because the list indexing in python starts from 0).

Comment: Thank you for your detail explain ! I checked them with this URL as well to comprehend them .